# How big or small should a Use Case Interactor be in Clean Architecture?

Tags: domain-driven-design, architectural-patterns

I’m trying to figure how best to define a Use Case using Clean Architecture and DDD.  Let’s say I have an application that handles the pick, pack and shipping of a delivery.  Here is the flow:

1. User enters a deliver to populate the screen with shipping information
2. User selects line items and clicks a button to Pick
3. User enters package information(e.g. weights and dims) and clicks a button to Pack.
4. User clicks Ship button to call an external system to get shipping labels

Here are the options I’m considering for defining my Use Case Interactors:

1. Create 4 Interactor classes, one for each step listed above
2. Create 1 Interactor class with 4 methods to handle the steps listed above
3. Create 3 Interactor classes
   a.    Interactor 1 would handle the Enter Delivery and Pick
   b.    Interactor 2 would handle the Packing
   c.    Interactor 3 would handle the Shipping

Answer (score 2):

Any of the three choices would do so long as the use-case interactors are created as a function that *purely represents* the business use case (that is to say, they have no knowledge of anything other than the business rules for which they are responsible).  I think that would qualify as a Clean Architecture -- a clear boundary between the business rules and the implementation details.

If I must make a choice, I would gravitate toward:

> Create 1 Interactor class with 4 methods to handle the steps listed above

Comment: @Tony Raimo - if you find the answer acceptable, please check it as such